# Installed mySQL 8, but want to go back to mySQL version 5.7

Tags: mysql

I have mySQL version 8.0.22 running on my Linux Mint 20.04 machine.
I want to install mySQL 5.7 instead, as version 8 is giving collation errors etc.

I had gone through few threads, but confused.
Kindly point me to any reliable resource or let me know how to do it.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score -1):

This's [MySql Version 5.7.3 For Linux](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.7.html)

Comment: If this answer helps you, don't forget to check it as right answer, please.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I would like to know how to remove mySql 8 completely and then install 5.7. Will it work that way or will it lead to errors if I do that. Any help appreciated.. thanks.